# Computing Quantile in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, distribution, quantile

Is there any built-in function in MATLAB to compute

0.025th  quantile of Binomial distribution with parameter n=60 and p=0.4

0.975 quantile of standard normal distribution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have the Statistics toolbox? If yes,

```
>> binoinv(.025,60,.4)

ans =

    17

>> norminv(.975,0,1)

ans =

    1.9600
```

If not, you could use the following equivalences:

- The inverse normal CDF can be expressed in terms of the `erfinv` function
- The binomial CDF can be expressed in terms of the `betainc` function

Answer (score 1):

First, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19932576/8239061) is correct and provides the direct, distribution-specific functions. However, there are more general functions that can do this for those needing a wider array of functions and probability distributions.

For those with the Stats toolbox, MATLAB introduced [probability distribution objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/working-with-probability-distributions.html) in 2013 which provide very convenient ways to work with distributions and statistical functions.

One can use [`makedist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html) to create the distribution objects needed.

```
% MATLAB R2022a
% Parameters
n = 60;
p = 0.4;
mu = 0;
sigma = 1;

% X ~ Binomial(n,p)
pdX = makedist('Binomial','N',n,'p',p)

% Y ~ Normal(0,1)  
pdY = makedist('Normal','mu',mu,'sigma',sigma)
```

Remembering that the quantile function is the inverse cumulative distribution function, calling [`icdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.icdf.html) gets the job done.

```
x = icdf(pdX,0.025)    % x = 17

y = icdf(pdY,0.975)    % y = 1.9600
```